# converting JSON data called from a URL and displaying it in a HTML table

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, json

I currently have a HTML file which calls a url that is pull data from mysql, and displaying it in json in to a very simple iframe. Ideally I would like to get it to display in a HTML table format, however I'm finding it a little tricky to convert json from a url. I plan to use Javascript. Any help guys? Please bare in mind I am pretty new to Javascript so please do comment any code, thank you in advance!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <title>Title</title>
   </head>
   <body>
    <h2>Header</h2>
    <div id="HEAD1">

    <iframe src="http://localhost:8080" width="1000"      
    height="1000"></iframe>





    </div>
    </body>
```

This is what the Json output looks like, its pretty big lol

```
 [{"address":"178795010","client_id":null,"expire":"2016-09-26 16:56:32","fqdn_fwd":"1","fqdn_rev":"1","hostname":"vagrant-20009.ipam.bskyb","hwaddr":"0800272022E6","state":"0","subnet_id":"500","valid_lifetime":"4000"},{"address":"178795011","client_id":null,"expire":"2016-09-26 16:58:48","fqdn_fwd":"1","fqdn_rev":"1","hostname":"vagrant-18992.ipam.bskyb","hwaddr":"0800270FB593","state":"0","subnet_id":"500","valid_lifetime":"4000"},{"address":"178795012","client_id":null,"expire":"2016-09-26 17:13:55","fqdn_fwd":"1","fqdn_rev":"1","hostname":"dhcp-client1.ipam.bskyb","hwaddr":"0800275EA5B9","state":"0","subnet_id":"500","valid_lifetime":"4000"},{"address":"178795013","client_id":null,"expire":"2016-09-26 16:56:17","fqdn_fwd":"1","fqdn_rev":"1","hostname":"vagrant-10873.ipam.bskyb","hwaddr":"0800275FCA93","state":"0","subnet_id":"500","valid_lifetime":"4000"},{"address":"178795018","client_id":null,"expire":"2016-09-26 17:06:16","fqdn_fwd":"1","fqdn_rev":"1","hostname":"vagrant-24830.ipam.bskyb","hwaddr":"080027707E62","state":"0","subnet_id":"500","valid_lifetime":"4000"},{"address":"3232250119","client_id":null,"expire":"2016-09-26 16:17:27","fqdn_fwd":"1","fqdn_rev":"1","hostname":"bobobobobobobobobob.ipam.bmarkskyb","hwaddr":"080027379A97","state":"0","subnet_id":"12","valid_lifetime":"100"},{"address":"3232250120","client_id":null,"expire":"2016-09-26 16:17:15","fqdn_fwd":"1","fqdn_rev":"1","hostname":"bobtheblob7.ipam.bmarkskyb","hwaddr":"080027063AD9","state":"0","subnet_id":"12","valid_lifetime":"100"},{"address":"3232250122","client_id":null,"expire":"2016-09-26 16:17:22","fqdn_fwd":"1","fqdn_rev":"1","hostname":"bobtheblob8.ipam.bmarkskyb","hwaddr":"800027A5E27A","state":"0","subnet_id":"12","valid_lifetime":"100"}]
```

Comment: you should use angularjs capabilities to achieve the same.

Comment: @ChaitanyaKurdukar is it possible you could show me an example of how this can be achieved please?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is the exact thing what you are looking for IMO.Check the `<tr ng-repeat="row in data">` which is making the trick, only thing is you need to replace "" with '' notation in json

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script
 src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>


 <div ng-app=""
  ng-init="data = [{'address':'178795010','client_id':null,'expire':'2016-09-26 16:56:32','fqdn_fwd':'1','fqdn_rev':'1','hostname':'vagrant-20009.ipam.bskyb','hwaddr':'0800272022E6','state':'0','subnet_id':'500','valid_lifetime':'4000'},
{'address':'178795011','client_id':null,'expire':'2016-09-26 16:58:48','fqdn_fwd':'1','fqdn_rev':'1','hostname':'vagrant-18992.ipam.bskyb','hwaddr':'0800270FB593','state':'0','subnet_id':'500','valid_lifetime':'4000'},
{'address':'178795012','client_id':null,'expire':'2016-09-26 17:13:55','fqdn_fwd':'1','fqdn_rev':'1','hostname':'dhcp-client1.ipam.bskyb','hwaddr':'0800275EA5B9','state':'0','subnet_id':'500','valid_lifetime':'4000'},
{'address':'178795013','client_id':null,'expire':'2016-09-26 16:56:17','fqdn_fwd':'1','fqdn_rev':'1','hostname':'vagrant-10873.ipam.bskyb','hwaddr':'0800275FCA93','state':'0','subnet_id':'500','valid_lifetime':'4000'},
{'address':'178795018','client_id':null,'expire':'2016-09-26 17:06:16','fqdn_fwd':'1','fqdn_rev':'1','hostname':'vagrant-24830.ipam.bskyb','hwaddr':'080027707E62','state':'0','subnet_id':'500','valid_lifetime':'4000'},
{'address':'3232250119','client_id':null,'expire':'2016-09-26 16:17:27','fqdn_fwd':'1','fqdn_rev':'1','hostname':'bobobobobobobobobob.ipam.bmarkskyb','hwaddr':'080027379A97','state':'0','subnet_id':'12','valid_lifetime':'100'},
{'address':'3232250120','client_id':null,'expire':'2016-09-26 16:17:15','fqdn_fwd':'1','fqdn_rev':'1','hostname':'bobtheblob7.ipam.bmarkskyb','hwaddr':'080027063AD9','state':'0','subnet_id':'12','valid_lifetime':'100'},
{'address':'3232250122','client_id':null,'expire':'2016-09-26 16:17:22','fqdn_fwd':'1','fqdn_rev':'1','hostname':'bobtheblob8.ipam.bmarkskyb',

'hwaddr':'800027A5E27A','state':'0','subnet_id':'12','valid_lifetime':'100'}]">


  <p>Data Table :</p>
  <table border="1">
   <thead>
    <th>address</th>
    <th>client_id</th>
    <th>expire</th>
    <th>fqdn_fwd</th>
    <th>fqdn_rev</th>
    <th>hostname</th>
    <th>hwaddr</th>
    <th>state</th>
    <th>subnet_id</th>
    <th>valid_lifetime</th>

   </thead>
   <tr ng-repeat="row in data">


    <td>{{row.address}}</td>
    <td>{{row.client_id}}</td>
    <td>{{row.expire}}</td>
    <td>{{row.fqdn_fwd}}</td>
    <td>{{row.fqdn_rev}}</td>
    <td>{{row.hostname}}</td>
    <td>{{row.hwaddr}}</td>
    <td>{{row.state}}</td>
    <td>{{row.subnet_id}}</td>
    <td>{{row.valid_lifetime}}</td>
   </tr>
  </table>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: A ~50KB library for such a simple thing as displaying a JSON in a table?

Comment: I am agree that this could be done without angularjs by using normal javascript too but computerNoob being a new to javascript this is pretty simple for him to implement and its a new standard that everyone is going for, Also IMO this is not the only thing computerNoob would need he could use the angularjs capabilities for the other part of his application too.

Answer (score 0):

You might do as follows by utilizing a `tableMaker()` function. It will take your data and will convert it into a table HTML. each object in your data array represents a row, object properties are the headers and object values are the table cell values. If you pass the second argument as `true`, then the headers are displayed.

```js
var tableMaker = (o,h) => { var keys = o.length && Object.keys(o[0]),
                            rowMaker = (a,t) => a.reduce((p,c,i,a) => p + (i === a.length-1 ? "<" + t + ">" + c + "</" + t + "></tr>"
                                                                                            : "<" + t + ">" + c + "</" + t + ">"),"<tr>"),
                            rows = o.reduce((r,c) => r + rowMaker(keys.reduce((v,k) => v.concat(c[k]),[]),"td"),h ? rowMaker(keys,"th") : []);
                            return rows.length ? "<table>" + rows + "</table>" : "";
                          },
 
    tableData = [{"address":"178795010","client_id":null,"expire":"2016-09-26 16:56:32","fqdn_fwd":"1","fqdn_rev":"1","hostname":"vagrant-20009.ipam.bskyb","hwaddr":"0800272022E6","state":"0","subnet_id":"500","valid_lifetime":"4000"},{"address":"178795011","client_id":null,"expire":"2016-09-26 16:58:48","fqdn_fwd":"1","fqdn_rev":"1","hostname":"vagrant-18992.ipam.bskyb","hwaddr":"0800270FB593","state":"0","subnet_id":"500","valid_lifetime":"4000"},{"address":"178795012","client_id":null,"expire":"2016-09-26 17:13:55","fqdn_fwd":"1","fqdn_rev":"1","hostname":"dhcp-client1.ipam.bskyb","hwaddr":"0800275EA5B9","state":"0","subnet_id":"500","valid_lifetime":"4000"},{"address":"178795013","client_id":null,"expire":"2016-09-26 16:56:17","fqdn_fwd":"1","fqdn_rev":"1","hostname":"vagrant-10873.ipam.bskyb","hwaddr":"0800275FCA93","state":"0","subnet_id":"500","valid_lifetime":"4000"},{"address":"178795018","client_id":null,"expire":"2016-09-26 17:06:16","fqdn_fwd":"1","fqdn_rev":"1","hostname":"vagrant-24830.ipam.bskyb","hwaddr":"080027707E62","state":"0","subnet_id":"500","valid_lifetime":"4000"},{"address":"3232250119","client_id":null,"expire":"2016-09-26 16:17:27","fqdn_fwd":"1","fqdn_rev":"1","hostname":"bobobobobobobobobob.ipam.bmarkskyb","hwaddr":"080027379A97","state":"0","subnet_id":"12","valid_lifetime":"100"},{"address":"3232250120","client_id":null,"expire":"2016-09-26 16:17:15","fqdn_fwd":"1","fqdn_rev":"1","hostname":"bobtheblob7.ipam.bmarkskyb","hwaddr":"080027063AD9","state":"0","subnet_id":"12","valid_lifetime":"100"},{"address":"3232250122","client_id":null,"expire":"2016-09-26 16:17:22","fqdn_fwd":"1","fqdn_rev":"1","hostname":"bobtheblob8.ipam.bmarkskyb","hwaddr":"800027A5E27A","state":"0","subnet_id":"12","valid_lifetime":"100"}],
    tableHTML = tableMaker(tableData,true);
myTable.innerHTML = tableHTML;
```

```html
<div id="myTable"></div>
```

`tableMaker()` function uses ES6 code so might need to transpile it to older ES5 version if you target browsers those don't support ES6.

Comment: what if i wanted to call it straight from the url instead? as that is my aim.

Comment: @computerNoob I guess then you first have to convert the received URI into a JSON string by `decodeURIComponent()` and then into a JS object by `JSON.parse()`. Such as  `tableData = JSON.parse(decodeURIComponent(url))`